# Are special characters in e-mail address possible?

Tags: email, utf-8

I'm using Apache Commons e-mail validator and it refuses to accept email address like:

```
ąźóęł@email.com
```

so I would like to ask if it's right to not allow them or I should change validator?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mail_address#RFC_specification contains all the info you need: a link to the official RFC specs, which characters are good, etc.

Comment: ...and specifically it says that, without quoting, only roman letters [a-zA-Z], numbers and certain punctuation is allowed in the local-part.

Comment: In addition to my edit to note that they ARE allowed, please see this answer for more details of the current status: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52133890/1981358